# Create GUI that finds inverse of matrix

Tags: java, user-interface, matrix, matrix-inverse

In JCreator, I am required to to create a program which allows me to find a matrix inverse, I have previously used a code to find a matrix inverse, but have trouble trying to get int GUI format.

Here  is my GUI outline so far,

```
 *Matrix
 *
 */


import java.awt.*;      //  Java Library
import javax.swing.*;       //  Java Library
import java.awt.event.*;        //  Java Library

public class Matrix extends JFrame{ //  class

private JTextField jtfSize;     //  Text field
private JTextField jtfElements;     //  Text field
private JTextField jtfResult;       //  Text field
private JLabel jlblSize;        //  Label
private JLabel jlblElements;        //  Label
private JLabel jblblResult;     //  Lablel
private JPanel entryPanel;      //  Panel
private JPanel buttonPanel;     //  Panel
private JButton jbtCalculate;       // Button

public static void main (String[] args ){       //  main
    Matrix Frame = new Matrix();        // Frame
    frame.setTitle("Matrix Inverse Calcualator");       //  Frame Name
    frame.setSize ( 500, 500 );     //  Frame Size
    frame.setLocation (400, 400);       //  Frame Location on Screen
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      //  Set Close Option
    frame.setVisible(true);     // 

}

    public Matrix(){    //  

    jlblSize = new JLabel ("Matrix Size:", JLabel.CENTER );     //  Centre Label
    jlblElements = new JLabel ("Matrix Elements: ", JLabel.CENTER );        //  Centre Lable 
    jlblResult = new JLabel ("RESULT: ", JLabel.CENTER );       // Centre Jlabel
    jtfSize = new JTextField(12);       // Text Field
    jtfElements = new JTextField(12);       // Text field 12 font
    jtfResult = new JTextField(12);     // Text Field 12 front
    entryPanel = new JPanel();      // Panel

    jtfResult.setEditable( false );     // make RESULT Field uneditable

    entryPanel.setLayout (new GridLayout (3,2) );       // Set layout manager of Panel

    entryPanel.add( jlblSize );     //  Add component to Panel
    entryPanel.add( jtfSize );      //  Add component to Panel
    entryPanel.add( jlblElements );     //  Add component to Panel
    entryPanel.add( jtfElements );      //  Add component to Panel
    entryPanel.add( jlblResult );       //  Add component to Panel
    entryPanel.add( jtfResult );        //  Add component to Panel

    add(entryPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);       // add entryPanel to frame

    jbtCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");        //  Add button and insert text for button
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();         //  Creates Panel for Button

    buttonPanel.add(jbtCalculate);      // insert Calculate button to panel

    add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);      // Panel layout

    jbtCalculate.addMouseListener(new List_ButtonCAL());        //  

    }
        private class list_ButtonCAL implements MouseListener{      //  

            public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event){        // 

                double x=Double.parseDouble(jtfSize.getText());
                double y=String.parseDouble(jtfElements.getText());

                jtfResult.setText(String.);

            }
        }

}
```

Now here is the code I am working off,
I am having trouble figuring out how to place this inside the GUI format.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Import Scanner library

class matrixinverse { // start of class
public static void main(String argv[]){ // start of main
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // input Scanner library
    System.out.println("Enter the dimension of square matrix: "); // Ouput on screen
    int n = input.nextInt(); // user inputs figure
    double a[][]= new double[n][n]; //
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of matrix: "); // Ouput on screen
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) // 
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            a[i][j] = input.nextDouble(); //

    double d[][] = invert(a); //

    System.out.println("The inverse is: "); // Ooutput on screen
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){ //
        for (int j=0; j<n; ++j)  { //
            System.out.print(d[i][j]+"  "); //
        } //

        System.out.println(); //
    } //
    input.close(); //
}   

public static double[][] invert(double a[][]){ //
    int n = a.length; //
    double x[][] = new double[n][n]; //
    double b[][] = new double[n][n]; //
    int index[] = new int[n]; //
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)  //
        b[i][i] = 1; // 
    gaussian(a, index); //
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; ++i) //
        for (int j=i+1; j<n; ++j) //
            for (int k=0; k<n; ++k) //
                b[index[j]][k]
                        -= a[index[j]][i]*b[index[i]][k]; //

    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){ //
        x[n-1][i] = b[index[n-1]][i]/a[index[n-1]][n-1]; //
        for (int j=n-2; j>=0; --j){
            x[j][i] = b[index[j]][i]; //
            for (int k=j+1; k<n; ++k) {
                x[j][i] -= a[index[j]][k]*x[k][i]; //
            }
            x[j][i] /= a[index[j]][j];
        }
    }
    return x;
} //

public static void gaussian(double a[][], int index[]){
    int n = index.length; //
    double c[] = new double[n]; //
     for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) 
        index[i] = i;

    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        double c1 = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<n; ++j){
            double c0 = Math.abs(a[i][j]);
            if (c0 > c1) c1 = c0;
        }
        c[i] = c1;
    }

    int k = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<n-1; ++j){
        double pi1 = 0;
        for (int i=j; i<n; ++i){
            double pi0 = Math.abs(a[index[i]][j]);
            pi0 /= c[index[i]];
            if (pi0 > pi1){
                pi1 = pi0;
                k = i;
            }
        }

        int itmp = index[j];
        index[j] = index[k];
        index[k] = itmp;
        for (int i=j+1; i<n; ++i)   
        {
            double pj = a[index[i]][j]/a[index[j]][j];

            a[index[i]][j] = pj;

            for (int l=j+1; l<n; ++l)
                a[index[i]][l] -= pj*a[index[j]][l];
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Any help at all will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A GUI should never find the inverse of a matrix. GUIs could let you enter a matrix; they could display the inverse of a matrix; but the inversion of the matrix should be done in non-GUI code.

Comment: It's an assignment for college. I'm required to do it in GUI format

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend researching MVC(model-view-controller) or some other sort of setup for GUIs. Since this is a fairly simple project MVC might be slightly overkill but the basis of it would be to have a separate class that runs the calculations, receiving and sending information to the GUI(view). In your case, when jbtCalculate is pressed the other class will read the information off of the GUI and then do the calculations before sending the data back. If you have any questions about MVC, some of the answers on [this link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54121/explain-model-view-controller) might help you start off.